# WAGTAIL forms to external DB

Tags: postgresql, azure, wagtail

I have a small research project, but so far I haven't found anything. I want to know if there's a way to use forms in Wagtail to be able to populate an external DB (postgres located somewhere else).

The idea is to create a back-office that is self-managed in wagtail and where the users can fill the forms with the data required and this data is to be stored on an azure postgresql cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Django's forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/). This is one scenario where using the Wagtail form builder is counter-productive: the Wagtail form builder is all about letting the content editor define the list of form fields within the Wagtail admin, but in your case the form fields are pre-determined by your external database structure, so specifying them within the Wagtail admin would be needless duplication of work.

See https://github.com/gasman/wagtail-form-example/commits/master for an example of integrating Django forms into a Wagtail page.